# Is there a way to change which wireless network is connected to when authenticating windows 7 AD clients using single sign on over wifi?

Tags: active-directory, authentication, wifi, single-sign-on

The situation:

Two domains. Two wireless networks.  Each domain's users have their own network for security reasons.  B is a child domain of A (A = domain.com, B = child.domain.com). Users in domain B cannot connect to A's wifi.  Users in domain A can connect to both wifi networks, but authentication is painfully slow on B's wifi (well over 10 minutes to sign in to Windows 7).

The computers being used are Win 7 laptops.

Both networks should be visible to all computers at all times.

The 802.1x/Single Sign On works for either one individually (when the wireless network profile for that domain is at the top of the list), but not both at the same time.  Would like a way to switch between the networks being used/connected to for authentication depending on the domain the user account belongs to.  I.e., if signed in as A/jsmith, it should connect to A's wifi and authenticate, log in and be connected to A's wifi.  If B/btahakin signs in, it should connect to B's wifi and authenticate, log in and be connected to B's wifi.

Is there any way to do this?

**I only have access to AD/GPO's for the laptops and the laptops themselves.**

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the wifi hardware you are using. Modern decent hardware, like Cisco, has a way to supply access points with a correct ssid using radius, which is now called NPS in Windows. So basically - yes, this can be done.

What is more disturbing, - according to your description it seems like both domain users are mixed in the single network. This is weird, because this is not the typical case of multi-domain AD setup.